# CS50 Problem Set 2--Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, encryption, cs50, caesar-cipher

So I've been working on this code for about a day now and finally managed to create the file without an error message popping up. As soon as I run it, though, this pops up:

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

`

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    int k=atoi(argv[1]);
    if (argc!=2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else if (argv[1]<0)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 2;
    }
    else if (argv[1]== NULL)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 3;
    }
    string plaintext= get_string("plaintext: ");
    printf("ciphertext: ");
    for(int i=0; i<strlen(plaintext); i++)
    {
            if(plaintext[i]>='a' && plaintext[i]<='z')
            {
                printf("%c", ((plaintext[i]-97+k)%26)+97);

            }
            else if(plaintext[i]>='A' && plaintext[i]<='Z')
            {
                printf("%c", ((plaintext[i]-65+k)%26)+65);
            }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

`
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Haven't really tried anything to resolve this yet.

Comment: First thing to do is run it in a debugger to find out which line it crashes on.

Answer (score 0):

Even without seeing where it core dumps, I can see a number of issues with the code.

First thing is that you try to dereference `argv[1]` before checking how many parameters there are. i.e.

```
int k=atoi(argv[1]);
```

comes before

```
    if (argc!=2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

If you run your program without putting in a value for the offset, this will cause a segmentation fault because C runtimes put a null pointer after the pointer to the last argument. So if you just typed `./caesar` on the command line, `argc` is 1 and `argv[1]` is `NULL`.

This is the most likely cause of your crash.

This line:

```
else if (argv[1]<0)
```

doesn't really make any sense. You're comparing a pointer to 0. In many (all?) implementations, pointers behave like  unsigned integers under comparison, so no pointer is ever less than zero.

This line

```
else if (argv[1]== NULL)
```

Is redundant if you have already checked that `argc` is two. Because, if `argc` is two `argv[0]` and `argv[1]` are guaranteed to point to strings.

---

On an unrelated note, I'd say that you should never do what that `cs50.h` header file does, which is have a typedef of something to `char *`. It just obfuscates what a `string` is.

Comment: It's not *by convention*, but the C standard *requires* `argv[argc] == NULL`.

Comment: @iBug I misremembered then. I've changed the wording.